# selenium verify text in html table populated by AJAX

Tags: selenium

I'm using the FireFox WebDriver for Selenium. I have a window that gets loaded via AJAX and my tests are inconsistent due to this.

I can put a 3 sec delay on the thread and it works everytime. All I'm doing is checking for the present of a row.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your Selenium tests are supposed to simulate a person using the site, so anything you do to circumvent what a human would do (sit and wait) could potentially lead to an erroneous result. In situations like this I see no problem in adding a delay while the AJAX loads (or fails) and then reporting that.

Answer (score 0):

the best way (IMHO) is to use fluent wait.
Anyway you have locators of the needed element (xpaths, or css selectors or etc.) and passing locators to fluentWait function you'll obtain needed web elements to interact with.
`fluentWait` function code provided below:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

it is important to note that *each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as NoSuchElementExceptions when searching for an element on the page.(c)selenium API documentation*

So you can set
*.pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)*
and during this interval will be verified wheter your AJAX  has returned or not.

some add info about fluent wait you can read [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

Assume

```
String cssLocator=...blablabla..  // is the css of the table row
```

you pass to the function:

```
   WebElement firstRow= fluentWait(By.cssSelector(cssLocator));
```

and in this way you obtain first row of your table.

Hope this got clear to you now)